# Google sign in no longer working?

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, google-authentication, securesocial

I've been seeing "Bad Request Error 400" for the last few weeks whenever using Google signin on my Play Framework website (https://www.cointouch.com/). SecureSocial Config as follows:

```
google {
    authorizationUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
    accessTokenUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
    clientId="[redacted]"
    clientSecret=[redacted]
    scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login profile email"
}
```

In the securesocial log, the following is shown before I see the error message in my browser

```
redirecting to: [https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login+email&client_id=[redeacted]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.cointouch.com%2Fauthenticate%2Fgoogle&response_type=code&state=[redacted]]
```

My redirect URLs are configured correctly in the Google API console.

I read that Google has deprecated some of their former signin APIs:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration

Is there a quick-fix I can apply to my SecureSocial setup?

Comment: I believe you fixed this by clearing your cookies, correct?

Comment: @jorge yes, thanks for reminding me. Have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tried many remedies, and with the kind assistance of Jorge I discovered this was something to do with cookies. Deleting cookies fixed it.